# kubuntu 22.04 error installing icons

Tags: 22.04

error when trying to install new icons hit the get icons button then hit install ,failed, error: settings invalid number of concurrent streams

this also happens when trying to install widgets

Comment: I'm not sure this is a Ubuntu problem, more of a KDE one. I've seen it recurrently and similar ones for ages and I can only state the obvious. First, try log out and in, try again. You can visit the Homepage link listed there, download the icons and put them in `~/.icons` Also: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/vfh7sv/comment/id661o6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 See links there: it's a KDE bug.

Comment: It worked till yesterdays systemd update then it stopped working

Comment: Its more then that i found several things are not working now since the systemd update yesterday like installing certain software in discover hangs up then produces the same error you can no longer acess sources via sources in app menu have to access it via drivers in settings or terminal so something is definitely boched up my system was perfect and the same errors occur on my asus laptop both running kubuntu 22.04

Comment: K systems log and krdc no longer work as well both systems